# Assigning method output to a variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter, ib-api

the below code will output the last price of a stock continuously until stopped as shown on the console.

What I would like to do is output the price in a tkinter label, but my code would not do it.

[image]

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

lass IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 4002, 123)



#Define the contract
stock_contract = Contract()
stock_contract.symbol = 'AMZN'
stock_contract.secType = 'STK'
stock_contract.exchange = 'SMART'
stock_contract.currency = 'USD'

#Request Market Data
app.reqMktData(1, stock_contract, '', False, False, [])
```

I tried modifying it like below so I can show it on a label but it does not work. When trying to print out **data** I get error **NONE**

```
data = app.reqMktData(1, stock_contract, '', False, False, [])
labellastprice_ticker5.configure(text=data)
```

Surely I am sure I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: I think you need a [mre] that clearly shows it working in one context but not in the tkinter context. Right now I'm not sure if there's enough code. You didn't indicate what libraries your code example is using but it's clear you're using several, it would be a lot more helpful if we knew what actual library functions and objects you were working with since otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: Have you ever tried to print out the value of `data`? it may not be what you expect.

Comment: If I go with only ‘’’ app.reqMktData(1, stock_contract, '', False, False, [])‘’’ then I get the output on the console that I have pasted as an image. It is just the output on tkinter label that I am struggling with

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638230/2855515 is a tkinter sample I wrote a while ago.

Comment: You can try calling `labellastprice_ticker5.configure(text=price)` instead of `print(...)` inside `IBapi.tickPrice()`.